# PHP $_SESSION for remote oracle database

Tags: php, database, oracle, session

So I have remote Oracle database to work with. I am trying to create simple admin and guest login with sessions or cookies whichever works best or is easy. I have html file for the form:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="login.php" method="get">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='username'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input type='password' name='password'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'><input type='submit'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

a login.php file

```
<?php

/* Set oracle user login and password info */
$dbuser = "xxxxx"; /* your deakin login */
$dbpass = "xxxxxx"; /* your oracle access password */
$db = "xxxxx";
$connect = OCILogon($dbuser, $dbpass, $db);
if (!$connect) {
echo "An error occurred connecting to the database";
exit;
}
/* build sql statement using form data */
$query = "SELECT * FROM login where username='".$username."' and password='".$password."'";

/* check the sql statement for errors and if errors report them */
$stmt = OCIParse($connect, $query);

if(!$stmt) {
echo "An error occurred in parsing the sql string.\n";
exit;
}
OCIExecute($stmt);
$valid=false;
while(OCIFetch($stmt)) {
    $valid=true;
}

if ($valid){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header('Location: test.php');
    /*echo "welcome" .$username;*/
    }
else
    echo "invalid username/password";
?>
```

---

and a test.php file.

```
    <?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    echo "Welcom ".$_SESSION['username'] . "This is your profile";
} else
echo "you must be logged in";
?>
```

---

I am trying to create a session of admin or guest and hide a link using if else statement from guest.

Every-time I am trying. I get "you must be logged in" from test.php
that is format of db connect I was given with and it is the first time I am working with remote database.

thanks in advance

Comment: in login.php where is your session_start()?

Comment: Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

That is the error I am getting When I include session start

Comment: That means at least some html was sent, make sure that session_start is the first thing, even a space before the opening PHP tag will cause this

Comment: Yes, I made sure of that. It is redirecting. but echo $username is not showing the logged in user

Comment: What will be the return value of OCIFetch? Your while loop seems suspicious. You can't call `session_start` after you output something to the browser. I suggest that you comment out the redirection and test. See if any error returned.

Comment: ocifetch asking for ociparse

Comment: Hahah, sorry. I mean the `session_start` error you got might be caused by one of your `echo` is called before you call the session_start. The redirection will prevent you from seeing the `echo`. So stop the redirection while you are testing. And before the while loop do `var_dump(OCIFetch($stmt))` to see what comes out.

Comment: `bool(true) invalid username/password` - without session_start in login.php

`Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /login/login.php:2) in /login/login.php on line 3
bool(true) invalid username/password`

^ - with session_start in login.php